# How to make a widget float?

Tags: front-end, java, gui-construction

Is there an option or way to make a GUIKit window remain in on top of other application's windows?

```
In[1]:= Needs["GUIKit`"] 
ref = GUIRun[Widget["Label", { "text" -> "Stay afloat!"}]]
```

I've looked through the docs and I can't find a way to do this yet.

```
In[3]:= Options@Widget
Out[3]= {InitialArguments -> None, Name -> None, 
 ExposeWidgetReferences -> Automatic, WidgetLayout -> Automatic}
```

But I suspect it is possible, because it is based on Java and it is poosible to do in java's Window class.

```
Window.setAlwaysOnTop(boolean)
```

If anyone knows what gui libraries that JLink is using under the hood here for GUIKit windows - that would be a really great place to start!

Comment: But you have seen that the source of ``GUIKit` `` comes with your *Mathematica* installation and you even have all java sources available, yes?

Comment: Yes, and I was surprised that the source was exposed - but I haven't yet found a solution.

Comment: Does my answer work for you too?

Comment: A glass of soda and two scoops of widget?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess all the important information can be found in the tutorial, specifically in the subsection

- [Access to the Java Object Layer](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/GUIKit/tutorial/AccessToTheJavaObjectLayer.html)

There, you see that you can easily extract the class that is used for widgets

```
<< GUIKit`
ref = GUIRun[Widget["Label", {"text" -> "Stay afloat!"}]]

First[ref]
(* « JavaObject[com.wolfram.guikit.swing.GUIKitJFrame]» *)
```

As shown in the tutorial, you can call methods on the java object directly, which makes it possible to do the following

```
First[ref]@setAlwaysOnTop[True]
```

On my machine this works and I cannot cover the window with another one any longer.